# Would a login system based on digital signing be a good idea?

Tags: authentication, openid, digital-signature

One of the goals of OpenID is to be resistant against the failure of any one corporation. This sounds good, but there is another problem: if the site your ID is hosted on goes down, so does your ID. I thought that there must be a login system that would be totally resistant to failure.

My idea is like this: I go to a website and I have to login. I give them my public key. The website sends me back some random data. I sign this data with my private key and send it back to them. If the signature is valid, I get logged in. This has the advantage that my ID is just my public key, so I don't rely on any external site.

To make it so that users don't have to remember there keys, the system could also optionally allow an OpenID-like system where my keys are hosted on some server and the original site redirects me there to login, and that site signs the data and sends it back to the original site, and I am logged in. This method would work similar to OpenID, but would allow me to back up my keys so if that site goes down, I can use another site.

Is this a practical system? Am I just wasting my time? Should I not reinvent the wheel and just use OpenID?

Answer (score 2):

Identity cards, like Windows Cardspace, are a good alternative because they are stored on your computer and can be backed up.  This is technically called the [Identity Metasystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_Metasystem) or [Identity Cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Card).

This is different from a centralized identity service like OpenID.  The good thing about the OpenID system is that the chance of everyone's identity server of going down is pretty small.  However, individually, each user can possibly experience an outage.

The InfoCard system by Microsoft is a good solution, although it has not been very popular.

This is not a new problem-- email signing and encryption is a similar solution to private/public key system.  GPG actually does have keystores where you can post your public keys so that people can verify your signatures.

If you're really wanting to avoid any possibility of an identity server being down(a pretty strict requirement), use CardSpace, or some other private/public key system where the users themselves have the keys, and only have to demonstrate that they have them by some challenge-response hashing algorithm.

Also, the cardspace solution is not strictly a Microsoft thing, there are plenty of applications for all operating systems.  I believe it is a public standard.

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to [how HTTPS works](http://www.verisign.com/ssl/ssl-information-center/how-ssl-security-works/).

With your idea, you need to take good care of your private key. What if your comnputer crashes, etc. Also what about logging in from someone eleses computer? Would you trust putting a thumb drive with your private key on it into someone elses computer?

This is also very similar to what the military does with ID cards with private keys embeded on a chip that they issue to service members. A member needs to put his ID into a special reader as well as logon with a unique ID and password that must be changed periodically. This is to take care of the case where a member looses his ID and someone else trys to use it.

So I guess my answer is yes, you have a good idea, but perhaps you just need to refine it some more.

Answer (score 0):

Use OpenID. It's so easy to set up and you don't have to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

[Windows CardSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480189.aspx) supports something like this. But it hasn't really taken off.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your system is that if you lose your key due to hardware problems or a system crash, you lose your only way to get to the sites you use that key for.

Comment: That's what the OpenID-like hosting option is for.

Answer (score 0):

I would say OpenID is sufficient.

I see a couple issues with your system

1. I need to have that key to login.  If I go out, and don't have the file on my person or hosted remotely, I'm out of luck.  I also may not be able to enter it on my cell phone or some other device.
2. You will also need to protect the key from loss.  Which likely means password protecting the key, which takes away alot of the convenience of the system.

What needs to happen for OpenID to be more resistant to ID provider failure, is for sites to allow multiple OpenIDs to be associated with an account, just like SO does.  So, your idea may end being workable, but I think the effort to get it working and adopted would be much greater than the work to get widespread adoption of sites allowing multiple OpenIDs.

Also, check this [link](http://blogs.adobe.com/simplicity/2009/02/using_tls_client_auth.html) for a description of TLS Client Authentication